# Prepared statement for create user in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've a question regarding PreparedStatement in Java and create user query.
I've following query and prepared statement, but it won't work:

```
String createUserQuery = "CREATE USER testit LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(createUserQuery);
statement.setString(1, userPass);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Prepare statement works only for DML, not for DDL commands, and `create user` command is DDL, so it does not work.

Comment: What happens when you try to build and run that code? Does it build? Does it throw an exception?